# Communication between PHP application with Web Cam

Tags: php, video, hardware, video-processing

In my website I am trying to interact the php application with Video Cam. I am not getting proper way to proceed. Please suggest me ????

Comment: What code do you have at the moment? Please update the question so we can take a look.

Comment: Sorry, right now i dnt have any prepared code for this. I have made a search over the internet but i could not get any return. So plz suggest me, in which way should i accomplish my Task???

Answer (score 1):

Php just doesn't work that way.
At least in a "web mode"

If you want to do this you have to (sadly) use flash AND php.

I advise you to use AMFPHP which is a really easy lib to implement and use to make Flash and PHP speak together (using RTMP protocol)

Have fun